# Wordpress: How to display post list with random thumbnail size per post

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I'm trying to make a portfolio page like this: http://themewich.com/gridstack/portfolio-fixed/
Does anyone know how to display post list with random thumbnail size per post like the example above?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The images on the site you mentioned are not being loaded with random sizes. They are all being served as the same size. The theme is then using Isoptope javascript plugin in order to resize the posts and display them in the grid you see.